# Betting Game with choosing integers that depends on how far apart they are

Tags: probability

From Finan's Probability Book 6.22

*George and Paul play a betting game. Each chooses an integer from 1 to
20 (inclusive) at random. If the two numbers differ by more than 3, George
wins the bet. Otherwise, Paul wins the bet. Calculate the probability that
Paul wins the bet.*

As far as I understand, the total number of combinations is given by $_{r+n-1}C_r$ which in this case, is $210$.

I calculated all the numbers that differ by no more than $3$ manually, reasoning thus, that $1$ has $4$ "partners" that differ by no more than $3$, and they are $1, 2, 3, $ and $ 4$.

$2$ also has only $4$ partners that differ by no more than $3$ because I already counted $(1,2)$

I continued for the first $17$ integers with each number having $4$ partners that differ by no more than $3$.

$18$ has only $3$ partners that were not already counted, they are $18, 19$ and $20$.

$19$ has $2$.

$20$ has $1$.

So in summary, all of the integers that differ by no more than $3$ from their partners are $17\cdot4 +3 +2 +1 =74$

and ${74 \over 210} = 0.3523$

but the official answer is $0.32$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your unordered pairs are not equi-probable.  The unordered pair $\{1,2\}$ is twice as likely as  $\{1,1\}$.  To avoid this, I'd stick to ordered pairs.

Comment: To do it with ordered pairs:  G has  $\frac 1{20}$ chance of picking any of the numbers.  If $G$ picks $1$, say, then the probability that Paul wins is $\frac 4{20}$ for the reason you give. If $G$ picks $2$, say, then the probability that Paul wins is $\frac 5{20}$ and so on. Just sum the cases.

Comment: So basically, I was wrong to not count (2,1) etc.

Comment: Well, not wrong exactly....though I always try to work with equi-probable events if possible.  If you want to use your unordered pairs you just need to keep track of their probabilities.  (but, really, it's easier to just work with the ordered pairs).

Comment: One could argue that it makes no sense for Paul to choose $1, 2 $ or $3 $, for instance, and he knows it, so he will definitely not choose them and this reduces the sample space. There may be further tricks, a game theoretical analysis would be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P_{(Paul)} = \frac{1+3+5+(17\cdot 7)}{^{20}P_2+20} = .32$$

Comment: Where are the 1, 3, 5, and 17*7 coming from?

Comment: $(20,20) = 1, (19,19), (19,20)$ and $(20,19) = 3$ and $(18,18), (18,19), (19,18), (18,20),$and $ (20,18) = 5$. All others $17$ and below have $7$.

Answer (score 1):

74 is the number of combinations that differ by less than 3 where the order doesn't matter. However, in this case, it matters. All you need to do is multiply by 2 and subtracting those that are repeated such as the combinations $(X,X)$. All combinations possible are equal to 400. so the answer is equal to $\dfrac {((74\times 2)-20)}{400} = 0.32$

Answer (score 0):

We canmap the pairs $(i,j)$ with $1\le i\le 20$,   $1\le i\le 20$, $|i-j|>3$ to other pairs as follows:
$$ (i,j)\mapsto\begin{cases}(i-3,j)&\text{if }i>j\\(i,j-4)&\text{if }i<j\end{cases}$$
Check that this map is injective and is onto $\{1,\ldots,17\}\times\{1,\ldots, 16\}$. Conclude that George wins with probability $\frac{17\cdot 16}{20\cdot 20}$